# TCP "proxy" to intercept TCP traffic with Spring integration

Tags: tcp, proxy, spring-integration

My situation is as follows. Currently, in my application, a commercial library is used to take an input, serialize it in some proprietary way, and then send it to a server via TCP. As I see from inspecting TCP traffic, certain input data, let's call it "the call key", is left "unscrambled" (that is, I can take the sequence of bytes sent to the server, and find in it the "call key").

I have to modify this as follows: intercept the TCP traffic, see if the "call key" is "key A", and then send the input to server A. If the call key is "key B", I need to send it to server B.

I was thinking to use Spring Integration for this purpose, though I don't know much about it (I have only run some sample projects).

Namely, I would like to set up a "TCP channel" (sorry if I use the wrong terminology) with an input endpoint to which the commercial library will send its input (localhost:myport); some component then examines the payload, finds out whether the "call key" is "key A", or "key B", and routes it to server A or server B accordingly.

Is this indeed possible (i.e. more or less easily achievable) with existing Spring Integration components?
If yes, could you indicate which Spring Integration components such solution might use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tcp-client-server-multiplex](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex) shows a mechanism for asynchronously proxying request/reply scenarios; you need something in the data to be able to correlate the reply to the request.

It uses an aggregator to do that.

With the simpler `tcp-client-server` sample, referenced in the README, gateways are used and the framework can take care of the correlation (but it will not handle high volume, unless you use a `CachingClientConnectionFactory` on the outbound side (which is really your only option if you can't add some data with which to correlate the replies).

If you are only talking about one-way messaging, then correlation is obviously not needed (and you don't need the aggregator infrastructure in the first example).

In either case, you would simply add a router in the flow to route to the A or B outbound endpoint.

There is a newer DSL-based TCP example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client) which routes dynamically.

Comment: Hi John. Were you able to solve your pb? If yes, how do you intercept tcp traffic?